# renameTo() in grails to rename an apk file to zip file

Tags: groovy, rename

I want to upload apk files. And then convert it to zip in order to extract some information.
I used renameTo() function but its not working.

---

```
 String newFilename = "new.apk"
 new File(f.getOriginalFilename()).renameTo(new File("new.apk"))
```

(f.getOriginalFilename() will return the name of an apk file) How exactly can I do renaming?

Comment: Try: `new File(f.getOriginalFilename()).renameTo( newFilename )` If that doesn't work, what does it do?  Any Errors?  What does `println new File(f.getOriginalFilename()).exists()` show?

Comment: it doesn't showning any errors and println is printing false.

Comment: It should print `true` or `false`

Comment: Right, so the file named `f.originalFilename` doesn't exist (is missing), which is why it can't rename it

Comment: f is an apk file that is being uploaded. and its in 'E:/myprojects/uploadproject/upload/image'. println "Uploaded File " + f.getOriginalFilename() is printing the apk file name.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47736/discussion-between-sag-and-tim-yates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. need to give the full path to the file. for example

```
new File( webRootDir + "/" + [folder name] + "/" +f.originalFilename ).renameTo(
    new File(webRootDir + "/" + [folder name] + "/" +appname+".zip") )
```

will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

And Groovier using GStrings:

```
new File("$webRootDir/$folderName/${f.originalFilename}").renameTo(new File("$webRootDir/$folderName/$appname.zip"))
```